# Display upcoming events including currently going and upcoming

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've slots with the column `event_starting_time` & `event_ending_time` which stores the starting and ending events with the date time format as `2016-06-17 23:00`.

So, in dashboard I needed to display all the events that are coming next plus the ongoing one.

Assume if the current time is 5th July 10.40PM. Suppose if I've a event with `event_starting_time` as `2016-07-05 22:30` (10.30PM) and `event_ending_time` as `2016-07-05 23:30`(11.30PM), then i want to show this event too in the list.

The below is my current query which only displays the upcoming one not the events which are actually happening right now.

```
$conditions = array('event_starting_time >=' => date("Y-m-d H:i"));
$parameter = array('conditions' => $conditions);
$slots = $this->Slots->find('all', $parameter);
```

The SQL query for above will be ,

```
SELECT * from Slots  where event_starting_time >= date("Y-m-d H:i");
```

I'm open to any of SQL or Cakephp solution.

Answer (score 0):

In stead of including H:i, you should only filter where the date is y-m-d and not more accurate. Otherwise you'll have to check an event for every seconds it's saved to. Try using simpler datetimes for global variables like this.

So it becomes:

`$this->Slots->find()->andWhere ('like', 'datetime', $variable);`

Answer (score 0):

If your condition is to include ongoing events, then you could simply test for the end of the event instead, ie

```
event_ending_time > value
```

That would include ongoing events (11.30PM end > 10.40PM current), as well as all upcoming ones.

Comment: `$conditions = array('event_ending_time >=' => date("Y-m-d H:i"));`
Include the equal sign to cover last minute.

Answer (score 0):

Ongoing event

```
select * from event where 
(event_starting_time < current) and (event_ending_time > current)
```